# .htaccess change name of parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know, there a some similar questions, but I cant find the right Rule, that worked...

If the value of the Parameter "go" started by "newsletter/", then, a new parameter "Section" should be generatet with the fix value "Newsletter".
The former value of the Parameter "go" will split and transfer to the new parameter "AWF".

How to change this:

```
index.php?go=newsletter/newsletter70
```

into:

```
index.php?Section=Newsletter?AWF=newsletter70
```

I've tried a lot like These

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^go=newsletter/(.*)
RewriteRule ^index.php?go=newsletter/(.*)$ index.php?Sektion=Newsletter?AWF=%1 [L]
```

I used "[L]", to stop other folowing rules.

Thank you very much!

Comment: The second question mark (`?`) does not make sense in the RewriteRule, it must be an ampersand (`&`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^go=([^/]+)/([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)$ /$1?Section=%1&AWF=%2 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: YES! It works! Geat! Thank you very much! And the best Thing of thise solution: It works even for other "sections", you could split it in the first line. I've leand very much.

Comment: `NC` means no case comparison so `go` and `GO` or `Go` will be matched.